# Can I have map and conatMap pipes run on same timer in rxjs?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have some code where I have an observable that will do different things in different pipes. Something like this wherein each pipe may have different filters to do different things to the various other observables:

```js
subject$.pipe().subscribe(another$);
subject$.pipe().subscribe(another2$);
subject$.pipe().subscribe(another3$);
```

Each "another" relies on the prior one such that I wouldn't want `another2$` getting values until `another$` was done. This worked great for me while all the pipes had `map` in them.

Is there a way to put things in order as it was, without arbitrarily adding concatMap to each pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at https://rxjs.dev/guide/scheduler

You just need to put `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` at the top of any pipe you want to follow suit with others that ARE using async methods.

https://jsfiddle.net/Dave_Stein/97w0b6dh/.